# How to install GDAL/OGR with GRASS vector support?

Tags: grass-gis, osgeo

The GRASS 6.4.3Svn for Windows that i have in my machine does not have GDAL/OGR support. Is there any library (libgrass) for Windows to add into existing GRASS installation. If not, how to build or install GRASS with OSGEO4W installer including GDAL/OGR support?

Comment: Here's a similar question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/2279/4119. Did the OSGeo4W installer not work for you? If not, what when wrong?

Comment: @katahdin - the question is not about installing GDAL/OGR with Python, but GDAL/OGR with Grass vector support which is not compiled in to GDAL/OGR by default and it doesn't look like it's included in OSGeo4W.

Comment: @Sanjeewa - I haven't edited your question in case I have misinterpreted your meaning, but I assume based on your [previous question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44613/ogr-python-bindings) that you mean: _The version of GDAL/OGR for Windows that I have installed does not have GRASS vector support. Is there a GRASS driver plugin for Windows to add to an existing GDAL/OGR installation. If not, how to build or install GDAL/OGR from OSGEO4W including GRASS support?_

Comment: The OSGeoW4 link in the question that I pointed to includes GRASS.

Comment: @katahdin - the question is not about installing GRASS which is available in OSGeo4W, but Grass vector support for GDAL/OGR. As per http://www.gdal.org/ogr/ogr_formats.html Grass vector support is not compiled in to GDAL/OGR by default and it doesn't look like it's included in OSGeo4W.

Comment: When you install GRASS from OSGeo4W you should certainly have GDAL/OGR support. What did you try in GRASS that makes you think GDAL/OGR is not available? Did you test first with the stable 6.4.3RC3 ??

Comment: I installed GRASS through OSGEO4W installer and found that GRASS vector support for GDAL/OGR is not included in the current OSGEO4W. Required to inform GRASS developer list about this.

Comment: This is incorrect. You need to select the correct packages.

Comment: In OSGEO4W installer, i cannot see gdal_grass package under libs

Comment: There is gdal_grass plugin under obsolete category. However it does not work with the stable GRASS release 6.4.x in OSGEO4W.

Comment: @markus If you have been able to install gdal_grass with other relevant packages, please inform of versions of such packages for the benefit of the others. I tried both gdal1.5_grass and gdal_1.6_grass plugins with GRASS 6.4.x stable release in OSGEO4W.But both did not provide gdal/ogr support within GRASS.

Comment: When i tried reading a GRASS vector file through external Python using OGR/GDAL Python bindings, I could not read the GRASS file because OGR/GDAL GRASS plugin to read GRASS data from outside GRASS is to be installed. This plugin is available in OSGEO4W under OBSOLETE category. However, it seems that it cannot be properly installed with GRASS packages that run with GDAL 1.9.x in OSGEO4W. I think the plugin needs to be updated.

Answer (score 2):

You need the [GDAL-GRASS plugin](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Compile_and_install_GDAL-GRASS_plugin) to be additionally installed.

For OSGeo4W, see the package info at

http://download.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/release/grass/gdal-grass/